# Constrained ordering of matrix elements in R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a numerical matrix.

I want to optimize it according to the following constraints:

1. Each column must add up to 100.
2. Each row should have a certain order, but this can be violated.
3. The initial values in the matrix are pretty close to a good solution.

**Question 1**: Is there a way to get to a solution using optimx or a similar R package?

I think I can get part of the way there if I sort each row so that the order will be correct.  Then I could evaluate it column by column as follows:

For a column *j*, I'll have a vector x[1,*j*], x[2,*j*], ... x[*i*,*j*].  Each of these elements will be constrained by the proceeding (*j-1*) and following (*j+1*) column. That is to say: x[1,*j-1*] < x[1,*j*] < x[1,*j+1*], x[2,*j-1*] < x[2,*j*] < x[2,*j+1*], and so on.  I would have the constraint function f(x) = 100 - x[1,*j*] - x[2,*j*] - ... - x[*i*,*j*].  If could find a solution where f(x) was pretty close to 0, then I could rescale each column and I would have a solution to the original problem as stated.

**Question 2**: Is there a good way to solve the constrained f(x) = 100 - x[1,*j*] - x[2,*j*] - ... - x[*i*,*j*] problem in R?

Naturally, if someone has a solution to Question 1, then Question 2 becomes superfluous.

---EDIT---
A few additional details.

1. Each column is independent of all other columns, excepting the ordering constraint on the rows.
2. It's just as good to subtract 5 from one element in the column or 1 from five elements in the column.
3. A good global optimization criteria might be as follow: penalizes the result based on how many steps out of order each element in the column is.  For instance, if one element is 2 steps out of order, and another element is 1 steps out of order than that column would have a score of 3. In this case, an optimal solution would be one that minimizes the score for all columns.
4. The row orderings do not have to be different.  We simply don't care if they are.
5. It's not quite a matrix balancing problem, because there's no constraint on what the rows should add up to, just the columns. Each row should generally add up to a different number. If there are 10 columns, one row might add up 1.7 the other to 300.

---END EDIT---

Thank you,

Comment: My first instinct is: Why not just sort the rows like you said, then scale the columns and be done with it? That will probably violate the order condition a bit, but you said that's OK. This solution is admittedly really naive, and I'm sure it's not actually a good one -- but I don't think the problem is well-defined enough as stated to say *why* this solution isn't good or what specific rules it would violate. So, can you clarify the actual constraints?

Comment: (1) Are you sure you want each column to add up to 100 while each row should be increasing in value? That is a bit contradictory. (2) This is like a **matrix balancing** problem. This can be solved as a quadratic programming model. I use this type of problem very often.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery That is the best solution that I've come up with thus far as well.  It seems to me like there should be a better solution that is not as quick to violate the order constraint.   For instance, after ordering, suppose x[1,3] = 27, the column x[:,3] added up to 105. If the ordered value one less than x[1,3] was 20, then I could change x[1,3] to 22.  This would change the column sum to 100 and it would not change the order of any other row.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I apologize for note being clear.  Each row should not be increasing in value.  Rather each row should have an order distinct from all other rows.  Would you be willing to link to an example of solving matrix balancing with quadratic programming?  If that's the solution, then that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

### Example QP-based matrix balancing model

The model is basically:

```
 minimize  ||A -A0||
 subject to linear constraints
```

where `A` is the new matrix and `A0` is the old one.

I don't know what "each row should have an order distinct from all other rows" means. So instead I use the constraint "each row should add up to 100". (Only a column sum constraint makes the problem a bit too simplistic: we just can rescale the columns).

So here we go.

1. Data

The data is as follows:

```
----     10 PARAMETER a0  (random) initial values

             j1          j2          j3          j4          j5          j6          j7          j8          j9

i1        4.263      17.022      11.457       6.722       6.552       5.257       7.647      17.269       2.275
i2       19.964      11.996      19.832      15.483       3.483      13.155       4.031       5.752      13.710
i3        7.834       7.677       3.498       3.852      12.193      16.787       5.385      13.649      15.741
i4        3.099      10.545       4.043      17.577       6.037       6.430      12.285      14.732      12.937
i5        8.853       3.236       6.970       1.884       7.432       4.460      13.269      11.654      15.629
i6       13.561      15.361      12.922       6.393       2.642       2.948      13.184      11.361       1.599
i7        2.383       4.338      10.987      15.254       4.384       1.649      12.117      12.803       8.398
i8        5.618       5.682       3.480      18.736       8.219      15.885       6.701       3.384      15.229
i9        4.838       1.096       6.123      10.497       3.874       4.309       7.282       7.021       7.120
i10      19.878       8.028       8.085      15.668       8.537      18.349       3.272      14.974       2.053
sum      90.292      84.982      87.396     112.065      63.355      89.228      85.173     112.599      94.690

  +         j10         sum

i1       10.504      88.968
i2        9.272     116.676
i3        6.770      93.387
i4        9.812      97.498
i5        6.658      80.046
i6       16.055      96.025
i7        7.816      80.128
i8        2.315      85.247
i9       19.316      71.477
i10      11.950     110.794
sum     100.467
```

2. Model

   ```
   minimize sum((i,j),sqr(a(i,j)-a0(i,j)))
   subject to
       sum(j, a(i,j)) = 100  for all i
       sum(i, a(i,j)) = 100  for all j
   ```
3. Solution

We can solve this with a number of solvers:

- a specialized QP (Quadratic Programming) solver
- Convex SOCP solvers
- General-purpose NLP solvers

Here are my results (I used an NLP solver):

```
 ----     35 VARIABLE a.L  final value

              j1          j2          j3          j4          j5          j6          j7          j8          j9

 i1        5.540      18.830      13.023       5.821      10.522       6.640       9.435      16.315       3.112
 i2       18.470      11.033      18.627      11.811       4.683      11.767       3.048       2.026      11.775
 i3        8.669       9.043       4.622       2.509      15.721      17.728       6.732      12.253      16.136
 i4        3.523      11.500       4.756      15.823       9.154       6.960      13.221      12.924      12.920
 i5       11.021       5.936       9.428       1.876      12.295       6.735      15.949      11.592      17.358
 i6       14.132      16.462      13.782       4.787       5.907       3.625      14.266       9.701       1.730
 i7        4.543       7.029      13.437      15.237       9.239       3.915      14.790      12.733      10.118
 i8        7.266       7.862       5.418      18.207      12.561      17.640       8.861       2.802      16.437
 i9        7.864       4.653       9.438      11.345       9.594       7.441      10.820       7.816       9.705
 i10      18.972       7.653       7.468      12.584      10.325      17.549       2.878      11.837       0.707
 sum     100.000     100.000     100.000     100.000     100.000     100.000     100.000     100.000     100.000

   +         j10         sum

 i1       10.763     100.000
 i2        6.760     100.000
 i3        6.587     100.000
 i4        9.218     100.000
 i5        7.809     100.000
 i6       15.608     100.000
 i7        8.959     100.000
 i8        2.946     100.000
 i9       21.324     100.000
 i10      10.026     100.000
 sum     100.000


 ----     35 VARIABLE z.L                   =      426.042  objective

 ----     35 PARAMETER d  differences a(i,j)-a0(i,j)

              j1          j2          j3          j4          j5          j6          j7          j8          j9

 i1        1.276       1.808       1.566      -0.901       3.970       1.383       1.788      -0.954       0.837
 i2       -1.494      -0.963      -1.205      -3.672       1.199      -1.388      -0.982      -3.725      -1.934
 i3        0.835       1.366       1.124      -1.343       3.528       0.941       1.346      -1.396       0.395
 i4        0.423       0.955       0.713      -1.754       3.117       0.530       0.935      -1.807      -0.016
 i5        2.169       2.700       2.458      -0.009       4.862       2.275       2.681      -0.062       1.729
 i6        0.571       1.102       0.860      -1.607       3.265       0.677       1.083      -1.660       0.131
 i7        2.160       2.691       2.450      -0.017       4.854       2.267       2.672      -0.070       1.721
 i8        1.649       2.180       1.938      -0.529       4.342       1.755       2.160      -0.582       1.209
 i9        3.026       3.557       3.315       0.848       5.719       3.132       3.537       0.795       2.586
 i10      -0.906      -0.375      -0.616      -3.083       1.788      -0.800      -0.394      -3.137      -1.346

   +         j10

 i1        0.259
 i2       -2.512
 i3       -0.183
 i4       -0.594
 i5        1.151
 i6       -0.447
 i7        1.143
 i8        0.631
 i9        2.008
 i10      -1.924
```

4. Some extensions/alternatives I often see

- A relative distance objective: `sqr(a(i,j)/a0(i,j)-1)`
- Maintain sparsity of A (keep zeros at zero)
- A RAS algorithm is also popular to solve these kind of problems
- Use an entropy objective
- Add additional (linear) constraints that are needed to make the final `A` consistent and usable for subsequent models

Comment: This is a really great solution, thank you.  I have a few follow-up questions generally related to me not clearly defining the problem.
1) Each row should generally add up to a different number.  If there are 10 columns, one row might add up 1.7 the other to 300.
2) Solutions should be penalized for changes that violate the row-wise order.  If `a[1,3] < a[1,4] < a[1,1] < a[1,2]` and `a0[1,1] < a0[1,3] < a0[1,4] < a0[1,2]` then that row should score 2 point.  A good solution would minimize the score for all rows.   
3) If possible, could you show some sample code calling the solver?

Comment: These constraints are non-convex (i.e. difficult), In general, they may require binary variables to model and this makes the model a MIQP (Mixed-Integer Quadratic Program). MIQP solvers are readily available (although most are not free or open source)..I did not use R in my example but rather a specialized optimization modeling language (for me this is a bit more efficient, especially when prototyping optimization models)..

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I take some comfort in your confirmation that this is indeed a difficult problem.